# Changing a font's number form in PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2013, typography, opentype

Some fonts, for example [Corbel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corbel_(typeface)), include several number forms: lining figures where the numerals are the same height as a capital letter and old-style or text figures where the numerals have varying heights and blend in with lowercase text. For example, in the following snippet the line in Segoe uses lining figures while the line in Corbel uses its default number form, old-style figures:

[image: lining and text figures]

(N.B. The text in that snippet is unimportant, it is just illustrative of the different height of the numerals.)

I have discovered from [this article](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/13484/use-advanced-font-ligatures-in-office-2010/) via [an answer on the Graphic Design SE](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/42162/4078) that I can change between the number forms in Word using the advanced tab of the font dialog:

[image: Screenshot form Word]

*QUESTION:* **How do I select Corbel's lining figures in PowerPoint?**

Comment: You are right, I made a mistake when copying the text from Word to PowerPoint. I have deleted my answer.

Comment: From my tests in the answer I deleted, I believe that the only solution is to choose your fonts with care, as some of them handle numerals in one way and the others in the opposite way. I don't think anything has changed in PowerPoint 2013.

Comment: @harrymc Corbel handles them both ways, but the trouble is switching between them within PowerPoint.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The short answer is, **you can't**. Not at the moment, anyway.

Microsoft has yet to introduce support for advanced typographical features for OpenType fonts for PowerPoint and Excel. Microsoft Word however, does "[support a limited set of OpenType features](http://practicaltypography.com/opentype-features.html)"

From this [old HowToGeek article](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/13484/use-advanced-font-ligatures-in-office-2010/) (this is apparently the one you linked in your question) I assume these features are available in Word, Outlook and Publisher.

However, according to [this Office Support article](https://office.microsoft.com/en-in/word-help/opentype-options-in-the-font-dialog-box-HA101809106.aspx), it is only available in Microsoft Word.

Source: [OpenType features article](http://practicaltypography.com/opentype-features.html) (practicaltypography.com)

---

EDIT: **I found a workaround**

While you can't enable OpenType features for a font in PowerPoint, you can however edit said font and create a new subset of the original containing glyphs for only the digits and use the edited font when you need to type numbers in PowerPoint.

Here's the result after about 15 minutes of editing the Corbel font online at [IcoMoon](https://icomoon.io/app)
[image: Corbel Edited - Icomoon.io]

You'll need to first [convert the TrueType (TTF) font to SVG](http://everythingfonts.com/ttf-to-svg) and then import the SVG file at [IcoMoon](https://icomoon.io). After that, select the glyphs for the numbers you wish to edit (make sure you choose the appropriate icons from the list as it is important to get this right. Check the height of the numbers for assistance. Look for icons that are centered) [image: select the icons you wish to edit]  and click on the pencil icon and move each number down by 6 points using the **Move Down** button.
(this is largely a trial and error process. You might need to experiment here. It helps to modify a few glyphs, download the font and preview them to see if you've got it right.)

[image: edit glyph]

After that, click on **Generate Font** and associate each glyph with the correct Unicode code point or simply associate them with the correct number by entering 0 through 9 in the boxes to the right.

[image: associate glyphs with correct Unicode values]

Finally, download the font, install it and use it to type the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

PowerPoint apparently shows each font with its own default numerals lining option.
In the below example the above is displayed in Calibri and below in Corbel font, and the numerals are handled differently :

[image: image1]

I therefore believe that choosing your fonts with care is the only way to change numerals lining
in PowerPoint, based on the tests detailed below.

I went as far as embedding a Word object in PowerPoint and copying into it text that used
the same font but with different advanced lining options, and got at first this perfect display :

[image: image2]

However, the moment I switched the focus from the object, the display suddenly became this:

[image: image3]

The display stayed this way also in presentation mode.
However, when I then clicked inside the object, so placing it again in edit mode, suddenly the 
display switched back to the previous image, with numerals lining now done correctly!

So confusedly, it seems like Word is used to edit the Word object, so numerals lining is supported
at that stage.
But after the editing is done, PowerPoint takes over and displays it in its own wretched way.

My tests were done using PowerPoint 2010 and remain to be verified with PowerPoint 2013,
but I do not believe that numerals lining in implemented at all in the PowerPoint display engine.
I think it is a horrible idea for Word and PowerPoint to use different display engines for text,
but this is the way it apparently works. As both seem to use the same
[Office Open XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats) document format, as seen
from the fact that Word can pick up where it left off, this is even more lamentable.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use [LibreOffice Impress](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/impress/), the presentation software in that F/OSS office suite.

It will read/write PPT and PPTX files (more complete success with former than latter, in my experience). It will allow you to configure the font option this way:

- select the text you want to have "lining numbers" for;
- click in the font-name dropdown, and add `:lnum=1` or, in more recent versions of LibreOffice, `:+lnum` to the font name (Corbel, in OP's case);`ᵃ`
- hit "Enter", and done!

It will look something like this:

[image: screenshot]

And you will have lining numbers in your Impress presentation. It isn't a *Powerpoint* solution, but it is worth knowing about. Powerpoint does enjoy many other features lacking in Impress, so it's a matter of trade-off when judging which is the better software in a given case.

(And worth knowing, too, that Impress will allow for embedding fonts in the presentation, which Mac Powerpoint will *not* do.)

---

<sub>`ᵃ` Note that if you wish to add further opentype styles, use ampersand: e.g. `:+lnum&smcp` to add also small caps.</sub>